# How to parse url with Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm using Meteor with another CMS, and am creating a url with the variables I need to run Meteor (ex. http://site.com?a=flash&b=hash). How to I make those variables usable, and get Meteor to ignore it as a location? When I load the url like that, my app doesn't load correctly, presumably because it thinks I'm requesting a different location.

Comment: Hi Trevor, does the answer provided answer your question? If so, please mark as answered. If not, please modify your question, and we'll be happy to try and help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using iron router, if there is a query string or hash fragment in the url, you can access those using the query and hash properties of the this.params object.

```
// given the url: "/post/5?q=s#hashFrag"
Router.route('/post/:_id', function () {
  var id = this.params._id;
  var query = this.params.query;

  // query.q -> "s"
  var hash = this.params.hash; // "hashFrag"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of the querystring in Meteor should have no effect unless you're using eg. Meteor Router to invoke different methods depending on the current URL.

If you want to parse the querystring, just parse it by hand with eg. (in coffeescript)

```
 querystring: ->
    qs = {}
    for pair in window.location.search.replace("?", "").split "&"
      [k, v] = pair.split("=")
      qs[k] = v
    qs
```

Which will return an object like:

```
{ "a": "flash", "b": "hash" }
```

Comment: weird - I'm not using any special routing methods. I have a function to parse the URL and get the variables, but the existing database collections aren't loaded if I add those vars to the querystring.

Comment: Indeed weird. I'm not able to reproduce that. Try figuring out what the exact problem is (make a new empty meteor app, keep adding things until it breaks) and try submitting an issue on Github?